# How long can water hold elevated pressure and energy after opening pressure cooker lid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy, pressure, water, fluid-statics

I noticed today that the water warmed up in pressure cooker (1.5 ATM) dissolves sugar much faster and much more than water cooked in 1 ATM.

I am interested in how long can water hold the high pressure after opening the lid. 
I noticed also that the sugar crystallized much more in the 1 ATM-cooked water than in 1.5-ATM-water.

How long can boiled water at 1.5 ATM hold its pressure and energy after opening the lid of the pressure cooker? 
I think the water can hold the water rather long time so keeping the temperature longer. 
However, I am interested in how much this could be, for instance if the volume of the pressure cooker is 2.5 liters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed today that the water warmed up in pressure cooker (1.5 ATM) dissolves sugar much faster and much more than water cooked in 1 ATM.

The effect you observe is one of *temperature*, not pressure. Water soluble substances dissolve quicker when the temperature is higher because the water molecules of hotter water have a higher average kinetic energy than those of colder water.

Water does [boil at higher temperature when held at higher pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water), that's the principle of a pressure cooker: decrease cooking times by increasing boiling temperature by increasing pressure.

> How long can boiled water at 1.5 ATM hold its pressure and energy after opening the lid of the pressure cooker?

The water loses its pressure almost *instantaneously* after opening the pressure cooker and water temperature also drops back to about $100 \text{ centigrade}$ very, very quickly, the boiling point at atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Can you estimate how quick is the drop of water from 1.5 ATM to 1.0 ATM? I managed to much more sugar to such water than boiled water at 1.0 ATM.

Comment: @Masi: the drop is very fast because boiling costs energy: the Latent Heat of Vapourisation, this causes causes the boiling point to be restored back to 100 centigrade in a matter of seconds rather than minutes. How much sugar dissolves per unit of time is a subjective experience, unless your experiment is carefully designed. I suggest confirmation bias is at play here.

Comment: Can you estimate how many seconds? I put the sugar to the pressure cooker, minimizing this way the pressure drop while keeping the lid open and while preventing the cooling effect from other environments.

Comment: @Masi: "preventing the cooling effect from the environment" doesn't help much here. Boiling water requires energy (Latent Heat of Vapourisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization). When you open the cooker, steam carries away much heat (Enthalpy) causing the temperature to drop very quickly, back to its equilibrium temperature. You could verify that using a kitchen temperature, if you wish.

Comment: Any experiment about the rate of the phenomenon?

Comment: @Masi: Sure. After the water has been boiling for a bit open the cooker and stick a kitchen thermocouple (TC) in the water, making sure the TC doesn't touch the bottom. Watch the temperature fall.

Comment: Actually, this could be done possibly even better with infrared thermometer. However, I am not sure how deep it can take the temperature. Probably, mostly surface because cumulative measurement.

Comment: @Masi: IR thermometers are not ideally suited to shiny or transparent surfaces. Much better for perfectly black stuff.

Comment: I will then put Coca-Cola to my pressure cooker and see how its temperature is conducted. Or do you have better idea?

Comment: @Masi: make sure you degas the coke completely!

Comment: Excellent point! I think otherwise much higher pressure could be reached, having a potential risk of breaking the pressure cooker. So I need to leave one class of coke for 24h on the table to have it free of bubbles.

Comment: All pressure cookers I know of have a pressure relief valve (actually more of a pressure setting valve, but...). The carbon dioxide will come out well before boiling starts.

Comment: @JonCuster: it's just a calibrated weight that sits on top of an outlet. It acts both as safety *and* pressure setting valve.

Comment: I've more seen spring loaded ones, but both designs are used in more official pressure relief valves as well...